# Custom UIToolbar within UINavigationController's rightBarButtonItem disappears when popping back to view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, rightbarbuttonitem

**EDIT 2:**
I have now fixed this issue. I was setting a custom background image for my UINavigationBar like so:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NavigationBarBackground" ofType:@"png"]]];
[navBar addSubview:imgView];
[navBar sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Which was fine for the first view controller on the UINavigationController's view controller stack, but any sub views were making this code re-run and placing the custom background to the front.

**The Fix:**
Simply remove all your code for the custom background on the navigation controller, then EXTEND the UINavigationBar class in the following way:

Create a new .h / .m file called UINavigationBar+CustomImage. Set the .h code to:

```
@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end
```

And the .m to:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBarBackground.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

And voila! Everything works fine now.

**--- END EDIT 2 ---**

I have a UINavigationController, which drills down like so:

```
HOMEPAGE > DETAIL PAGE > MAP VIEW
```

The DETAIL PAGE adds a custom UIToolbar (with three buttons) to the rightBarButtonItem within viewDidLoad like so:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 1.0, 157.0, 44.1)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NavigationBarBackground" ofType:@"png"]]];
[tools addSubview:imgView];
[tools sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[tools setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:127/255.0 green:184/255.0 blue:72/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[imgView release];

NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:NULL];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Map.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMap:)];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourite.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:NULL];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
```

This displays perfectly when viewing the DETAIL VIEW page, and when I go to the MAP VIEW, the custom UIToolbar disappears (as expected), however, when going back to the DETAIL VIEW, the custom UIToolbar is no longer visible. It is there, though, as I can still tap the area where the 'Map' button should be, and it pushes me back to the MAP VIEW.

Would you know how I can get this UIToolbar to display again when going back to the DETAIL view?

I have tried rebuilding the custom UIToolbar in viewWillAppear, which has the exact same effects as above.

**EDIT** - This works if I put the code that builds the custom UIToolbar within the viewDidAppear method. I don't like this solution though, as the view slides back, *then* the custom rightBarButtonItem appears. Is this something to do with the navigation controller not being initalised before the page is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

If it works in viewDidAppear you could try viewWillAppear. In general, I've never seen a UIToolbar set as a UIBarButtonItem, so I wouldn't necessarily expect standard behavior. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: nope viewWillAppear doesn't work - the custom toolbar is there, but invisible. If i tap where the buttons were displayed, the functionality still works (i.e. the methods still get called).

Comment: strange. maybe on viewWillAppear you could call setNeedsDisplay on the toolbar... or even consider adding it in viewWillAppear and removing it in viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

Apple UI APIs often fail in unusual ways when you try to do anything even slightly unusual (even things that *should* work), and trying to insert a UIToolbar into a rightBarButtonItem definitely falls into my definition of "unusual".

What you really should be doing is hiding the navigation bar and adding the UIToolbar as a subview of your view controller's main view. Alternatively you could avoid UIToolbar completely and implement the buttons yourself in a custom view.